# Adding a dot after display quote with csquotes

Tags: csquotes, quoting

I have the following code using csquotes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{displayquote}[Author]
    Quotation text
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

I'd like to have a period added after (Author), as in, "(Author)." If I put the dot after the quote text, it looks like ".(Author)" and if I put it in the option, as in "[Author.]", it ends up looking like "(Author.)"

How do I add the dot after the parenthesis?

Comment: You should look at sections 8.6 and 8.7 of the csquotes manual, specifically on how to redefine `\mkcitation`. note, however, that this will impact `blockquote` and `textquote` both of which also have the optional `[<cite>]` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{#2#1}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{displayquote}[Author][.]
    Quotation text
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]